# How can port scan software obtain a local IP?

Tags: router, logging

How can port scan software obtain a local IP?

My home network is behind a Netgear DG834PN router with DGTeam firmware.

I accept that port scans are a fact of life. I get very few and most are to IPs that have never existed at my location except for the following which occurs from time to time:

Wed, 2019-10-30 23:20:41 - TCP Packet - Source: 23.228.101.195 Destination: [local IP] - [PORT SCAN]

The 'local IP' belongs to my public web server. No other local IP of mine appears in the logs as a destination. I use a slightly unusual local IP range albeit within one of the established ranges.

Edit one:

I doubt that any of the activity I have seen on my logs is harmful but I would like to gain a better understanding of the port scan entries.

My log preferences are set to include:

1 - Attempted access to blocked sites

2 - Connections to the Web-based interface of this Router

3 - Router operation (start up, get time etc)

4 - Known DoS attacks and Port Scans

I do not log normal activity.

DMZ is not enabled.

The only permitted inbound service is port 80 for the web server.

I have a dynamic IP and use a DDNS service to point to my router.

My understanding is that port scan logs should show the source IP of the originating device and a destination IP which should be my allocated WAN IP at the time.

I don't understand why some destination IPs are not mine or occasionally the local IP of my server.

Comment: Advanced Port Scanner (Famatech) does that quite handily - locally but not remotely.  One of your machines may have something like this running

Comment: Not installed on my network. The log shows a well known remote port scan source.

Comment: Packet Sniffers (Comm View and Wire Shark) can scan other machines and show Port Numbers along with IP addresses.  Wire Shark is free but Comm View is licensed

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but if you have a public web server set up to intercept all inbound traffic (e.g. as part of a [DMZ](https://kb.netgear.com/1118/How-do-I-configure-a-device-to-be-in-the-DMZ-on-my-NETGEAR-router) on your router), rather than explicitly port forwarding particular ports, all scan traffic would likely be sent to that server. Regarding the "local IP", perhaps this is simply a result of the logging itself. My personal router logs are all in the format `remote IP` to `local IP` for my public web server contacts. This hardly seems abnormal.

Comment: Please see edit one above.

Comment: Where are you seeing this log message? Does it relate to port forwarding you set up?

Comment: Isn't that simply 23.228.101.195 trying port 80, which is forwarded to your web server, hence showing its internal IP address in that log?

Comment: The message is in router logs.  I would expect the logs to replicate header information. Why would logs show action the router did not take such as local server IP?

Comment: Just guessing: as a regular setup for a consumer router would only have a single public IP address, which would then be the very same for all incoming requests, one might argue that showing the more specific mapped local private IP address in the log (for _"Destination"_) makes much more sense? And maybe the log then shows the internal IP along with "PORT SCAN" even if only a single port of a larger range was mapped/forwarded? All guessing aside: the external server at 23.228.101.195 would surely neither know, nor care, about your internal private IP address.

Comment: I apologise for providing incorrect information. It is now clear to me that all destination IPs relate to my web server. The WAN IPs were the dynamic ones assigned at the time. These tools discover my server LAN IP: https://www.ipvoid.com/port-scan/ https://www.speedguide.net/portscan.php but I have been unable to discover how they do it. Are there any changes I could make to stop such tools getting my web server LAN IP?